# How to find most frequent code(varchar) from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to find most frequent code within CodeID which is in same code_group from a table.

For example, from original table

```
ID     CodeID      Name      Code     Code_group
1         1         A        101          0
2         1         A        102          0
3         1         B        102          0
4         2         C        201          0
5         2         C        201          0
6         2         D        202          0
7         2         E        202          0
8         3         F        101          1
9         3         G        103          1
10        3         G        104          1
11        3         G        104          1
```

I want output like the below.

```
ID     CodeID      Name      Code     Code_group    Selected_code
1         1         A        101          0             102
2         1         A        102          0             102
3         1         B        102          0             102
4         2         C        201          0             NULL
5         2         C        201          0             NULL
6         2         D        202          0             NULL
7         2         E        202          0             NULL
8         3         F        101          1             104
9         3         G        103          1             104
10        3         H        104          1             104 
11        3         H        104          1             104
```

Even though code of 8th ID is same in CodeID: 1,it is not in the same Code_group.

So For CodeID: 1, Selected_code would be 102.
it must be counted within exactly same Code_group.

=======================================

I have tried it like the below. **I should not use ID for this one.**
From TableA

```
with m as
(
    select 
        CodeID,
        Name,
        Code,
        Code_group,
        cnt,
        Selected_code = ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Code_group order by cnt desc)

        from( select CodeID, Name, Code,Code_group
        ,count(*) over (partition by Code,CodeID) as cnt from tableA
        group by CodeID, Name, Code, Code_group,
    ) as t  
    group by  CodeID,
        Name,
        Code,
        Code_group, cnt
)
select a.CodeID,
        a.Name,
        a.Code,
        a.Code_group, b.Code as Selected_code, cnt 
from(select
     CodeID,
        Name,
        Code,
        Code_group,Selected_code,
        cnt
    from m) as a left outer join
    (select CodeID,
        Name,
        Code,
        Code_group,Selected_code,
        cnt
 from m where selected_Code=1) as b on a.CodeID = b.CodeID and a.Code_Group = b.Code_Group 
    order by a.CodeID, a.Code_Group
```

The problem of this is
*With statment* makes my table distinct. It shows only one row if there is exactly same data such as ID 1,2.
Also, I cannot make *NULL* if there is exactly same frequencies.

---

What should I add to get my desired output?
Or is there any better approach for this?

Comment: can you explain why the `Selected_code` for `ID 1` is `101` and `ID` 4 to 7 is `NULL` ? Also why `102` is selected and not `201` or `202`, these 3 has the same frequency

Comment: @Squirrel I'm sorry. I forgot to edit Selected_code to 102 for ID 1.

Even though ID 1 to 7 are in the same "Code_Group", Selected_Code must be calculated by the same CodeID which is under "Code_Group". So, Code_Group is like outer circle and CodeID is like inner circle.

For ID 4 to 7, there are two numbers which have same frequencies. It cannot be decided and I would like to state them as NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CTE `cte` find the highest frequency code by `Code_group` and `CodeID` using `dense_rank()`

CTE `selected` check for any `Code` with same frequency and exclude them.

Final query just select from the original table and `LEFT JOIN` the `selected`

```
with 
cte as
(
    select Code_group, CodeID, Code
    from
    (
        select Code_group, CodeID, Code, 
               r = dense_rank() over (partition by Code_Group, CodeID
                                          order by count(*) desc)
        from   tableA
        group by Code_group, CodeID,  Code
    ) c
    where c.r = 1
),
selected as
(
    select Code_group, CodeID, Code
    from
    (
        select Code_group, CodeID, Code, 
               cnt = count(*) over (partition by Code_group, CodeID)
        from   cte
    ) s
    where s.cnt = 1
)
select a.*, 
       Selected_Code = s.Code
from   tableA a
       left join selected s on  a.Code_Group = s.Code_Group
                            and a.CodeID     = s.CodeID;
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ff49f2345caffa25b70bd8a10d0a0834)